# ¿Se pueden filtrar datos con campo concatenado?

Tags: sql-server

estoy haciendo esta consulta:

```
SELECT RD.idDeduccion AS ID, CONCAT(E.Nombres,' ',E.Apellido_Paterno,' ',E.Apellido_Materno) AS 
Empleado, TD.Descripcion AS Tipo_Deduccion, RD.Monto, RD.No_Pagos, RD.Fecha_Registro, RD.Fecha_Fin
FROM Registro_Deducciones AS RD
INNER JOIN Empleados AS E ON E.idEmpleado = RD.idEmpleado
INNER JOIN Tipos_Deducciones AS TD ON TD.idTD = RD.idTDeduccion
WHERE RD.Estado = 1
```

Pero quisiera saber si esta consulta la puedo filtrar mediante este campo:

```
CONCAT(E.Nombres,' ',E.Apellido_Paterno,' ',E.Apellido_Materno) AS Empleado
```

Por ejemplo algo asi:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_Emp_GetbyName
@Nombre varchar(200)
AS
SELECT RD.idDeduccion AS ID, CONCAT(E.Nombres,' ',E.Apellido_Paterno,' ',E.Apellido_Materno) AS 
Empleado, TD.Descripcion AS Tipo_Deduccion, RD.Monto, RD.No_Pagos, RD.Fecha_Registro, RD.Fecha_Fin
FROM Registro_Deducciones AS RD
INNER JOIN Empleados AS E ON E.idEmpleado = RD.idEmpleado
INNER JOIN Tipos_Deducciones AS TD ON TD.idTD = RD.idTDeduccion
WHERE RD.Estado = 1 AND CONCAT(E.Nombres,' ',E.Apellido_Paterno,' ',E.Apellido_Materno) LIKE 
CONCAT('%', @Nombre, '%')
```

Algo así, no se si me de a entender.

Comment: ¿Lo has probado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo de varias formas, te recomiendo que hagas uso de una tabla temporal, en donde insertes los datos con tu campo concatenado y posteriormente apliques un select sobre ese campo de tu tabla temporal, la solucion seria mas o menos la siguiente

```
DECLARE @Nombre varchar(200) ='NOMBRE'

CREATE TABLE #TEMP_DATOS(
ID INT,
Empleado VARCHAR(MAX),
Tipo_Deduccion INT,
Monto DECIMAL(19,2),
No_Pagos DECIMAL(19,2),
Fecha_Registro DATETIME,
Fecha_Fin DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP_DATOS
SELECT RD.idDeduccion AS ID,
CONCAT(E.Nombres,' ',E.Apellido_Paterno,' ',E.Apellido_Materno) AS Empleado, 
TD.Descripcion AS Tipo_Deduccion,
RD.Monto,
RD.No_Pagos,
RD.Fecha_Registro,
RD.Fecha_Fin
FROM Registro_Deducciones AS RD
INNER JOIN Empleados AS E ON E.idEmpleado = RD.idEmpleado
INNER JOIN Tipos_Deducciones AS TD ON TD.idTD = RD.idTDeduccion

SELECT * FROM #TEMP_DATOS
WHERE Empleado like '%'+@Nombre+'%'
drop table #TEMP_DATOS
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias

Comment: Esto es una forma de convertir una consulta lenta en algo aún más lento. No solo se leen todos los datos disponibles, también se escriben en otra tabla y se vuelven a leer. Tres veces el trabajo original.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la concatenación y filtrar en la misma consulta:

Cambiaré las llamadas a `concat()` por el operador `+`, solo por cuestión de gustos y facilidad de lectura, el resultado debiera ser el mismo.

```
SELECT   RD.idDeduccion AS ID
       , E.Nombres + ' ' + E.Apellido_Paterno + ' ' + E.Apellido_Materno AS Empleado
       , TD.Descripcion AS Tipo_Deduccion
       , RD.Monto
       , RD.No_Pagos
       , RD.Fecha_Registro
       , RD.Fecha_Fin
  FROM Registro_Deducciones AS RD
       INNER JOIN Empleados AS E ON E.idEmpleado = RD.idEmpleado
       INNER JOIN Tipos_Deducciones AS TD ON TD.idTD = RD.idTDeduccion
 WHERE RD.Estado = 1 
   AND E.Nombres + ' ' + E.Apellido_Paterno + ' ' + E.Apellido_Materno LIKE '%' + @Nombre + '%';
```

Comment: Pero no hay problema con esta consulta, osea, si le pongo un nombre no me da error por no saber a que campo se refiere?, o lo toma todo como si fuera solo un campo?

Comment: Toma la concatenación, que es lo que quieres comparar. Digamos que el nombre completo es `'Juan José Pérez López'` (resultado de la concatenacion), y `@Nombre` tiene `Juan%López`, el registro coincidirá, que es lo que entiendo que buscas.